# NaN error in android

Tags: java, android

Am creating an android app for students attendance percentage.
When I run my app am getting the result as NaN. I pass two float values from main activity to activity A1. But in my app the "e2" field is showing the value "NaN". Till now I can't find my error. It must be in dividing the float values.

What's the mistake in my code?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package shafir.arraytest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sort(View v) {
        EditText e1, e2, e3, e4, e5;
        char ch = 0;
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text4);
        e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text5);
        Button b1;
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);
        int i1, i2, i3,c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        float tot,att;
        i1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        i2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        i3 = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
        tot=Float.parseFloat(e4.getText().toString());
        att=Float.parseFloat(e5.getText().toString());
        if ((i1 == i2) && (i1 == i3)) {
            c1 = i1;
            c2 = i1;
        }
        if ((i1 == i2) || (i1 > i2) && (i1 == i3) || (i1 > i3)) {
            c1 = i1;
            ch = '1';
        }
        if ((i2 == i1) || (i2 > i1) && (i2 == i3) || (i2 > i3)) {
            c1 = i2;
            ch = '2';
        }
        if ((i3 == i1) || (i3 > i1) && (i3 == i2) || (i3 > i2)) {
            c1 = i3;
            ch = '3';
        }
        switch (ch) {
        case '1':
            if (i2 > i3) {
                c2 = i2;
            } else {
                c2 = i3;
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            if (i1 > i3) {
                c2 = i1;
            } else {
                c2 = i3;
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            if (i1 > i2) {
                c2 = i1;
            } else {
                c2 = i2;
            }
            break;
        }
        Intent in1 = new Intent(this, A1.class);
        in1.putExtra("c1", c1);
        in1.putExtra("c2", c2);
        in1.putExtra("tot", c1);
        in1.putExtra("att", c2);
        startActivity(in1);
    }
}


`


----------


----------



`
**This is my Activity A1:**

package shafir.arraytest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class A1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a1);
        edit();
    }

    public void edit() {
        EditText e1, e2, e3;
        float ex, patt, internal,tempp,tot1,att1;
        int g1, g2,tempsum, matt = 0;
        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.great1);
        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.great2);
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inter);
        Intent in2 = getIntent();
        g1 = in2.getIntExtra("c1", 0);
        g2 = in2.getIntExtra("c2", 0);
        tot1 = in2.getFloatExtra("tot", 0);
        att1 = in2.getFloatExtra("att", 0);
        tempsum=g1+g2;
        ex = (float) (tempsum*0.075);
        tempp=att1/tot1;
        patt = (float)(att1 / tot1) * 100;
        if ((patt > 90) && (patt <= 100)) {
            matt = 5;
        } else if ((patt > 80) && (patt <= 90)) {
            matt = 4;
        } else if ((patt > 70) && (patt <= 80)) {
            matt = 3;
        } else if ((patt > 60) && (patt <= 70)) {
            matt = 2;
        } else if ((patt >= 50) && (patt <= 60)) {
            matt = 1;
        } else {
            matt = 0;
        }
        internal = ex + matt;
        e1.setText(Float.toString(ex));
        e2.setText(Float.toString(tempp));
        e3.setText(Float.toString(internal));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could clean up that code? E.g. using descriptive variable names (instead of c1, i1, etc.) and maybe cutting down the length of it a bit? This will help greatly with indentifying problems.

Comment: And check what the values of `tot1` and `att1` are. If there is a problem with the `e2` field. This may be the origin.

Comment: I would assume that tot1 = in2.getFloatExtra("tot", 0); and att1 = in2.getFloatExtra("att", 0); return 0

Comment: No... This app would prompt the user to enter the value of tot and att....

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that tot1 is 0 and then you get NaN because you can't divide by 0.
If that's not the case, please add some print statements to see in what point does tempp turn to NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error: I made a mistake in passing the values from main activity.
I used the same variable names `c1` and `c2` for float. Now it's cleared, my app works fine.